# cannot install 'Fury' in python

Tags: python

I want to use this code:

```
from dipy.viz import has_fury
from fury import window, actor
```

so at first I installed the DIPY and Fury. but when I run `pip install Fury` it didn't work and this error was showing:

ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'vtk'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I tried to uninstalled vtk but I couldn't and same error showed to me.

Comment: Use virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that this package's metadata doesn't include a list of files that belong to it. Most probably, you have installed this package via your OS' package manager, so you need to use that rather than `pip` to remove it.

You can either reinstall the package for `python` while ignoring the installed version with

```
pip install --ignore-installed vtk
pip install --ignore-installed fury
```

or if you don't wanna do that you can use a virtual environment and install the libraries in the virtual environment.

see: [Virtual Environments in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)